# Android sdcard in SHARED state

Tags: android, android-sdcard

You guys have been good to me so far in my android development travails.  I'm up against another blocker.  I'm trying to write data to the sdcard, but it's in the shared state.  The sdcard is *not* mounted as a windows drive, afaict.  It doesn't show up in the file explorer, but when I check the state, via

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
```

state is "shared", which prevents me from writing to it.  What to do?

Oh, btw, I'm running Windows 7.

TIA,
Joel

Answer (score 0):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html
the state value of MEDIA_SHARED means that it is present in the phone, not mounted in the droid os, but mounted via the usb.....

So even though it is not mounted in windows it would seem that your droid thinks it is.

Maybe try unplugging it and replugging it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Windows 7. When you plug it, did you check the notification bar of your phone, you have to mount the SD card, then only it can be seen in file explorer.